# Breeze - define key to add entity

Tags: breeze

I want to add an Entity to my Manager.
The manager is saved in my MasterViewmodel, and I'm working with knockout.

```
Error: Cannot attach an object to an EntityManager without first setting its key or setting its entityType 'AutoGeneratedKeyType' property to something other than 'None'
```

My code:

```
var item = {           
        GuidUser: masterViewModel.UserID,
        GuidProject: ProjectID,
        Start: startTime,
        End: stopTime,
        Description: workDone,
        IdCustomer: null,
        timestampId: null,
        Charged: false,
        ToCharge: toCharge,
        };
var item2 = masterViewModel.breezeProjectManager().createEntity('Timestamp', item);
masterViewModel.breezeProjectManager().addEntity(item2);
```

But how to set a Key?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var item2 = masterViewModel.breezeProjectManager()
           .createEntity('item', { timestampId: breeze.core.getUuid() });
```

Comment: see this link for a full explanation if you are creating the entity as a javascript model and not from the database. http://www.breezejs.com/samples/nodb

Answer (score 0):

When any EntityType is first defined it should have at least one DataProperty that has it's 'isPartOfKey' property set to true.  The metadata for any EntityType is either materialized as a result of the metadata being returned from the server or is created on the client.  In either case, the "EntityType' metadata must be created before any entities of the type can be created.

My guess is that you have not yet either fetched the metadata or created it, when you first tried to create your entity.  In your case, you can make a fetchMetadata call before you try to create your entity. i.e.

```
breezeProjectManager().metadataStore.fetchMetadata().then(function() {
   .. perform your creation and add logic here.
}
```

The other possibility is that whichever field ( or fields) are defined with 'isPartOfKey' = true, have not been set to a nonnull value before calling 'addEntity'.

Comment: but how to set 'isPartOfKey'= true for my Guid in the timestamp?

Comment: How is the entityType being defined, via a fetchMetadata call or directly by creating the entityType?